# How do I dynamically add and name an HTML Select list withJquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-select

I am trying to build a form dynamically which adds elements based upon parent select lists.

```
<select name="itemlist[]"  class="itemlist" >
   <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">select</option>
   <option value="1">1 item</option>
   <option value="2">2 item</option>
   <option value="3">3 item</option>
   <option value="4">4 item</option>
   <option value="5">5 item</option>
   <option value="6">6 item</option>
</select>
```

When an option is selected the jquery event will dynamically add 1-x textboxes based on the select list value. IS it possible to name the textboxes as parent.child to follow the selectlist name then textbox[]
e.g. (index is the select list value selected and is fetched using the jquery function)

```
  $("#mydiv").append('<div>Items:<input type="text" class="textboxitems" name="itemlist[' + index + '].textbox[]"  /></div><br>');
```

Does this seem correct? Is it even possible to name the Parent/Child arrays in this way? If yes to both I should be able to retrieve the input from `itemlist[0].textbox[0]` and so forth?

Many thanks for pointers.

Comment: Quit confusing what you are asking for. Can you post the HTML output you expect with the value selection?

Comment: So what the issue are you facing in your js code ?

Comment: Sorry, I will try and explain more.
I have 6 drop down lists named as an array[]
If the first is clicked and a value selected it will dynamically add x amount of textboxes to the html with names of textboxarray[]
Can I name them parentarray[].textboxarray[] ?